# Getting Type AgGridModule does not have 'emod' property during angular 12 migration

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am getting this

```
**Uncaught Error: Type AgGridModule does not have 'emod' property**
```

While i **migrate my angular app from 8 to 12.**

Its building without any errors and when i **serve** it is showing the above error in my console log.

I already imported components of ag grid in my module.

And updated **package.json** with latest ag grid version as

```
"ag-grid-angular":"25.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "25.2.0"
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Migrating from angular 8 to 12 too with ag grid. Do you find a way to fix this @NithinPaul ?

Comment: @FolabiAhn  and Nithin : One year later , I am facing the same issue while upgrading my app from Angular 12 to 13 . I am using `ag grid 15.0.0` . Were you able to find any solution to this issue or were you able to understand why this error is coming up ?